# How to keep the Alt-Tab menu on the second monitor in Ubuntu?

Tags: multiple-monitors, ubuntu-9.10, alt-tab

I'm running the latest Ubuntu version on my laptop, and every day when I arrive at my office I turn on the laptop and plug everything on. That includes a monitor that happens to be larger than the laptop's monitor.

I always do my work on the desktop monitor, so I'd like for the Alt-Tab menu to always pop-up on this one. Instead, it's configured to pop-up whichever monitor the mouse is on (which makes sense, but doesn't work for me).

Anybody know a way to change that?